How can I set up 35 tablets for a class of school children, so that I can manage all the device settings remotely?
We have purchased 35 Lenovo M8 tablets to use for online survey data collection. The all have 4G and will not be used on wifi. We will give the tablets to children and ask them to fill in an online survey on Chrome/Google app.
Setting them up has been a nightmare. Installing all the updates etc is an ongoing process. I have signed up for a google account using my institutional email address (the uni I work at) and am signing myself in to each, but I can't apply safesearch settings due to it being an adult account. I am sure there is an easier way but unsure how to proceed. I tried googling some childish buzzwords to bring up adult content and was easily able to turn safesearch off.
I have found some solutions referring to 'Google play for education' that seems outdated.
I have been manually downloading the Find My Device App too so I can name each tablet with a number and we can find them if one goes missing.
Edit: I can see it has also auto-downloaded a bunch of games like Cat Tile and Booking.com with the updates. If there is a way to bulk delete these from all the devices this would save my weekednd.

You will need to use Multi Device Managers for that. See some questions around that but please note asking for recommendations is off-topic// I have no exposure to such

You need MDM (Mobile Device Management) for this.

this may not seem as a quick solution, but it will solve it.
you can install Google family link on all of them, sync them all with one google (child) account.
now you can set controls, locks and restrictions on all devices simultaneously.
you can restrict adult content and they cannot install new apps without your approval.
does that seem right?

Google’s Family Link app is designed to help you set ground rules and guide your child’s experience as they explore online. Your child will become part of your Google family group, which you can use to share Google services with your child and up to four other family members //OP wants to manage 35 devices. //Your solution is not going to work

you can sync all devices with one child account. it will have the same restrictions

Thanks, in which case it may be possible but I am still skeptical of 35 devices with the same account

why should amount matter?  you install Google family link on all of them, sign in with one account as a child, then all settings are the same... Even chat gpt says I'm right

Related article: https://phandroid.com/2020/07/06/how-many-android-devices-for-each-google-account/

@MorrisonChang thanks, also answers here
